# Pandas Counts with different level

Tags: python, pandas

I have raw data looks like df, how can I made df to df1?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["A","A","B","B","B"],
                   "B":["N","N","N","S","S"],
                   "C":["E","E","NE","NE","NE"],
                   "D":["y","n","n","y","n"]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":["A","N","E"],
                    "B":["N","N","S"],
                    "C":[2,1,2],
                    "D":[1,0,1]})
```

Comment: Can you explain better?

Comment: what is N N come from  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC (I guess first column A in `df1` is `['A','B','B']` )

```
df.groupby(['A','B']).agg({'C':'count','D':lambda x : sum(x=='y')}).reset_index()
Out[285]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  A  N  2  1
1  B  N  1  0
2  B  S  2  1
```